# Why do cars rotate during a "small overlap" crash test?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, collision, torque

I was watching a ["small overlap" car crash test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurance_Institute_for_Highway_Safety#Small_overlap_frontal_test) video and I noticed that the car tended to rotate around to the right side during the collision (see the figure below). My question is **why does the car rotate?**

This is the link to the video: https://youtu.be/dfG4SqPYcSA

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate but related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20784/226902 .  In short and not invoking "torques" or physics jargon: the half impacting the wall wants to stop, the other half wants to continue straight. However, the two halves are "rigidly" connected so the half that wants to continue straight drags the other one to "go around" the obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Car collision]

As the car hits the obstacle, the latter exerts a force $F$ on the former. This force is eccentric with respect to the CoG (the small cross in the center of the car schematic) and this causes a torque (moment) $\tau$ about the CoG:

$$\tau=Fd$$

With Newton's Second Law, the torque causes angular acceleration $\alpha$:

$$\tau=I\alpha$$

where $I$ is the inertial moment of the car about the CoG.

In other words, the car starts rotating about the CoG.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your answer.  a torque causes angular acceleration due to a force. in the video there is nothing pushing the car from the side to make it rotate.

Comment: When the car hits the obstacle, the obstacle (which is immovable) starts exerting a force $F$ on the car.Because of the shape of the obstacle, $F$ is offset with respect to the CoG. This causes torque about the CoG and with Newton's Second *angular acceleration*. The whole thing is an elementary application of $\text{N2L}$ for rotation.

Comment: So there is no need for a force from the side: torque acts about a point (or about an axis). Here, torque is provided by $F$.